# CSS drop down menu disappears when using Internet Explorer 9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, drop-down-menu

I have a CSS menu that I am trying to build. It works great with text and anchor links, but I used the same CSS for a drop down menu with social media like buttons (facebook, twitter, ect) everything works great except in IE9! I swear this browser will be the death of me! I have read it looks like the :hover is the issue that I need to maybe to a mouseover or something with JS! My expertise in that area is limited  and I have no idea what to do.

This is the HTML

```
<ul id="nav">
<li>Share This Page
    <ul>
        <li>
                    <div id="social_body">
                       <div id="social_left">
                         <g:plusone size="tall"></g:plusone>
                       </div>
                       <div id="social_right">
                         <div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-layout="box_count"     
                        data-width="55" data-show-faces="true"></div>
                       </div>
                     </div> 
                </li>
        <li>
                    <div id="social_body">
                      <div id="social_left">
                          <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-
                             button" data-count="vertical">Tweet</a>
                             <script>!function(d,s,id){var                                  
                             js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)                                 
                             [0];if(!d.getElementById(id))
                             {js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="
                             //platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
                             fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}
                             (document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
                      </div>
                      <div id="social_right">
                         <script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" 
                             type="text/javascript"></script>
                             <script type="IN/Share" data-counter="top"></script>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                 </li>
                 <li><div id="share_footer"><a href="http://www.brandonturpin.com" 
                             target="_blank">Zen Cart Module</a> by Brandon Turpin</div>
                 </li>
    </ul>
        </li>
            </ul>
```

And here is the CSS

```
/*------------------------------------*\
    RESET
\*------------------------------------*/
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
}
fieldset,img{
    border:0;
}
address,caption,cite,code,dfn,th,var{
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:normal;
}
caption,th{
    text-align:left;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
    font-size:100%;
    font-weight:normal;
}
q:before,q:after{
    content:'';
}
abbr,acronym{
    border:0;
}


/*------------------------------------*\
    DROPDOWN
\*------------------------------------*/

#nav{   color: #1e598e;
    list-style:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    /* Clear floats */
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    /* Bring the nav above everything else--uncomment if needed.
    position:relative;
    z-index:5;
    */
}
#nav li{
    text-align: center;
    margin-right:10px;
    position:relative;
}


/*--- DROPDOWN ---*/
#nav ul{
    background:#fff; /* Adding a background makes the dropdown work properly in IE7+. Make this as close to your page's background as possible (i.e. white page == white background). */
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.8); /* But! Let's make the background fully transparent where we can, we don't actually want to see it if we can help it... */
        height:auto; 
        padding-left: 5px; 
        padding-top: 10px; 
        padding-bottom: 5px; 
        padding-right: 5px; 
        border: 2px solid #e3e3e3;
        width: 14em;
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px; /* Hide off-screen when not needed (this is more accessible than display:none;) */
}
#nav ul li{
    float:none;
}
#nav ul a{
    white-space:nowrap; /* Stop text wrapping and creating multi-line dropdown items */
}
#nav li:hover ul{ /* Display the dropdown on hover */
    left:0; /* Bring back on-screen when needed */
}
```

Im a little lost!! Dang IE9

Comment: clean up your code. Post only the necessary part of the code & not all the stuff like fb like boxes etc.

Comment: Another thought: It might be useful to see the HTML as rendered, meaning after the social media links have been inserted.

Comment: You can't reuse `ID`s like that, convert `social_body`, `social_left` and `social_right` to `class`es.

Comment: According to my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/XjTqk/) this code actually works the same in IE9 and Chrome aside from obvious layout bugs having to do with the like buttons. What do you want us to do? what is your question?

Comment: When I hover over the social media parts it disappears, as long as I hover over the back ground area it stays up but not when I hover over the social media parts

Comment: The jsfiddle works for me fine also. I imagine that means that some other style/script is conflicting with this one, that's usually the reason in these cases.

Comment: Although this may be irrelevant using the IE Developer toolbar, please check what rendering engine you are using. In compatibility mode IE9 uses the IE7 rendering engine. In this case if you navigation is using z-index that may be the culprit...just a thought :)